# how to secure access/download AWS S3 files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is anyone familiar with how to secure access/download S3 files?

I tried this:

```
$file = $client->getObjectUrl( $bucket, $key, '+30 seconds' );
```

but it does not work.

I get access denied.

It was working just before updating the policy. After implementation policy it does not work.

This is policy that has been updated.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1415115909152",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "",
            "Action": "s3:
",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/temp/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/files/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/images/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-056dsdsdcbf13ba59"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```